# Check if an Edit Text that only accepts number is not empty and the number is equal or less than 100

Tags: android, validation, user-input, is-empty, range-checking

I'm building an application for receiving grades and I want to make sure that the Edit Texts are not empty and the values are less or equal to 100
I wrote this line but it crashes the application

```
if(Integer.parseInt(editText.gettext().toString()) > 100 || editText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
{
//Error message for example
}
```

and this is the logCat

> 09-04 18:21:06.331    8649-8649/com.example.nima.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.nima.myapplication, PID: 8649
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3827)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3822)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
>               at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
>               at com.example.nima.myapplication.MainActivity.me(MainActivity.java:22)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3822)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml where you have declared edittext make sure that you put the following attribute in edittext element

```
android:inputType="number"
```

And change above code to this :

```
 if(editText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() || Integer.parseInt(editText.gettext().toString()) > 100 )
    {
    //Error message for example
    }
```

you first need to check if text is not empty

Answer (score 1):

### First You Put In Your XML EditText Input Type=Number

Then Write This Code

```
If(edittext.getString().toString().Trim().lenght()>0)
{
     If(Integer.parseInt(editText.gettext().toString()) <= 100 )
     {

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control what digit should enter use `android:digits=""`

`android:inputType="number"` enforce to open number type keyboard still user can press other char like "**#,.**" than may cause **NumberFormatException**

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789"
/>
```

**android:digits="0123456789"** only accepts **0123456789** in `EditText`, not any other char

> Before converting any string integer you must check if it is **empty**

```
String strNumber=editText.getText().toString().trim();
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strNumber) || Integer.parseInt(strNumber)>100){
   // show your error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to switch the 2nd ans 1st expressions of the if.  Because when the program runs it checks firstly the 1st expression and then the 2nd.

So... when you don't have any value on the editText the getText().toString() return this "" and its impossible to parse to Int that value so you have to check first the length() and after that check if the number is bigger than 100

```
if(editText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() || Integer.parseInt(editText.gettext().toString()) > 100 )
{
//Error message for example
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your logcat states that you are entering a String where the code requires a Integer.

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException:

What i would suggest is store the EditText value in a different String and then check typecast it into Integer, many a times the compiler gets confused there.

Hope this helps :)