# Numeric input to find out what user is willing to pay

Tags: android, input, numeric, android-inapp-purchase

I am building an android app where users can choose what amount they want to pay for an item. But I do not want to sell the items to cheap, so minimum accepted amount is `.20`.

Based on previous questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317647/check-if-an-edit-text-that-only-accepts-number-is-not-empty-and-the-number-is-eq)) I have written so far

```
if(editText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() || 
Integer.parseInt(editText.gettext().toString()) > 0.2 )
{
//Error message for example
}
```

I want to display the currency so that the user know in what currency they are about to pay the amout they choose. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402172/android-market-in-app-purchase-how-to-get-the-currency-a-user-will-pay-in/25076649#25076649) post but I do not know how to use the information in my code above.

I am new to this; sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: have u tried that library? 
https://github.com/BlacKCaT27/CurrencyEditText

Comment: @ZarNiMyoSettWin no need to introduce libraries for simple problems

Comment: @ZarNiMyoSettWin that does look promissing but unfortunatelly, I am obviously too much a beginner to see how to implement that -.-

Answer (score 0):

Please add below class:-

```
class CustomRangeInputFilter implements InputFilter {
    private final double minValue;
    private final double maxValue;

    public CustomRangeInputFilter(double minVal, double maxVal) {
        this.minValue = minVal;
        this.maxValue = maxVal;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dStart, int dEnd) {
        try {
            // Remove the string out of destination that is to be replaced
            String newVal = dest.toString().substring(0, dStart) + dest.toString().substring(dEnd, dest.toString().length());
            newVal = newVal.substring(0, dStart) + source.toString() + newVal.substring(dStart, newVal.length());
            double input = Double.parseDouble(newVal);

            if (isInRange(minValue, maxValue, input)) {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(double a, double b, double c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

And add filter in `EditText` like below code:-

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new CustomRangeInputFilter(0f, 50f)});
```